# How to converting dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

All,

I have a dictionary called ALMs that looks like this:

```
[OrderedDict([(u'attributes',
               OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Obligations__c'),
                            (u'url',

                         u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Obligations__c/a0P3600000G0gWaEAJ')])),
          (u'Id', u'a0P3600000G0gWaEAJ'),
          (u'Name', u'ALM-17-000435'),
          (u'RecordType',
           OrderedDict([(u'attributes',
                         OrderedDict([(u'type', u'RecordType'),
                                      (u'url',
                                       u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/RecordType/01236000000SRWdAAO')])),
                        (u'Name', u'Asset')]))]),


OrderedDict([(u'attributes',
               OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Obligations__c'),
                            (u'url',
                             u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Obligations__c/a0P3600000G0gWbEAJ')])),
              (u'Id', u'a0P3600000G0gWbEAJ'),
              (u'Name', u'ALM-17-000436'),
              (u'RecordType',
               OrderedDict([(u'attributes',
                             OrderedDict([(u'type', u'RecordType'),
                                          (u'url',
                                           u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/RecordType/01236000000SRWdAAO')])),
                            (u'Name', u'Asset')]))]), 
...<continues>
```

I am trying to map that to a DataFrame using this function:

dfInstr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ALMs)

I get as a result this:

[image]

The problem is that I need the 'Attributes' sub-dictionary 'RecordType' 'Name' in the main data frame as well.

In other works, I need "RecordType" to be "Asset" and not the a sub-dictionary.

Any ideas on how to "elevate" a subordinated dictionary?

---- HERE IS AN EXMAPLE OF THE DESIRED OUTPUT ------

[image]

Comment: do you have a sample output, how your final data frame should look like?

Comment: Sure - see above - pasted into the original question